# Removing a lease from dhcpd

Tags: linux, dhcp

Is there a way to set the lease for a single dhcp client to a very short time in isc dhcp?  I'm trying to do this for troubleshooting purposes but I don't want to potentially end up handing out duplicate IPs.

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting up a host statement for the single client you are testing with (not sure if this will work), so somewhere in your dhcpd.conf file you add:

```
host test-client {
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.123;
    default-lease-time 1024;
}
```

You'll need to fill in the desired values for these, including your test client's mac-address (hardware ethernet). Choose a unique fixed address that is outside of your dhcp pool, and set the desired lease time.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for a site like ServerFault, where they can help you with sysadmin/pc support stuff.